# Wireless debugging Android Chrome app on desktop (Mac) Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, android, debug, google-chrome-devtools, nexus-5

Pre-story:

Nexus 5X has USB-C to USB-C cable out-of-the-box which is obviously not compatible with USB-A without any addition equipment (USB-C to USB-A cable). Both of the mentioned above cables seem to be quite expensive, and I don't want to buy *another* cable for the newly purchased phone.

Problem:

I need to debug a website in Chrome on Android device - Nexus 5X - and see what is exactly happening with a page on Chrome on my Mac without USB cable connection. I know that this is possible via [port forwarding](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging) feature Google Chrome dev-tools has.

The main idea is that I do not need to debug native Android apps so all the suggested steps with `adb` would not make any sense.

I am able to access web apps running on my localhost Apache web server (device ip address:port number), but I cannot see what's exactly happening on the device screen if something is broken.

[Same link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging) suggests that first I need to connect my device via USB to use it afterwards on without the USB and then configure the port forwarding. This means that I need to do connect/disconnect procedure every time I need to debug a website, what does not seem very convenient.

Question:

How can I debug Nexus 5X Android 6.0.1 Chrome app (44.0.2403.133) to my desktop Chrome app (53.0.2785.116 (64-bit)) running on Mac OSX El Capitan? Both devices are on the same network, under the same Google account.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking in this problem for the last days and here is what I have found out:

I have connected with Kayce Basques - one of the authors of the [Google remote debugging tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging) and he confirmed that there is currently no official way to arrange wireless debugging. Citing his words:

> The remote debugging workflow depends on Android's USB Debugging feature.

The other thing what I have looked into was wireless debugging with [Genymotion](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYyPCm7qHPAhWGnpQKHabvAxoQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.genymotion.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFe_83y8u2kkTCsdtEigYhL4Wskrw) Android emulator. I have made it work. Here is how:

1. Genymotion Android emulator has native OS images of many devices as I was looking specifically into Nexus 5X 6.0.0 I have just chosen to download this image.
2. After the image was downloaded I run the image, went to the device settings and enabled USB debugging

[image: Nexus 5X Android 6.0.0 emulator image]

3. After that I fired up the Android native browser and went to the webpage of my interest

[image: Google official webpage opened on the Android emulator]

4. On my Mac Chrome app I have typed `chrome://inspect`

   [image: Chrome desktop app devices view]
5. Desktop view I have clicked `inspect` just below the webpage address and got this magic window

[image: Google Chrome devtools]

Now I am able to see what is actually happens within the page without connecting an actual Android device. Just for the sake of re-assuring I tested everything on the actual Nexus 5X 6.0.0 and seems to work seamlessly.

Question is still open though, even though you can say that there is a confirmation from Google, I believe there are still hacks or work arounds and I would like to see those.